# My horizontal drop down with CSS, sub navigation menu items are being displayed on top of each other

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, nav

my sub navigation menu items are being displayed on top of each other

here is the code:

```
/* NAVIGATION */ .nav-bar {width: 100%; height: 80px; background-image:url(../images/bg-menu80.jpg);}

.nav-hold {overflow: hidden;}

.nav-list {float: right;}

.nav-list li {float: left; width: auto; position: relative;}

.nav-list li a {text-decoration: none; display:block; padding: 30px 7px 20px 7px; color: #f9f9f9; font-size: .9em; font-weight: bold;}

.nav-list li ul {display: none;}

.nav-list li a:hover {text-decoration: none; display: block; padding: 30px 7px 20px 7px; color: #000; font-size: .9em; font-weight: bold; background-color: #e7e4e4;}

.nav-list li a:hover li{display: block; position: absolute; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.nav-list li a:hover li{float: left;}

.nav-list li:hover li a{ background-color: #333; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; color: #FFF;}
```

---

```
<ul class="nav-list" id="navigation"><!--Menu list-->
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
<li> <ul><a href="members.html">Members</a>
<li><a href="board.html">Board of Directors</a></li>
<li><a href="committee.html">Committee</a></li>
</ul></li> <li><a href="join.html">Join Us</a></li> <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
<li><a href="rules.html">Rules &amp; Guidelines</a></li> <li><a href="archive.html">Archive</a></li> <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li> <li><a href="#">Login</a></li> </ul><!--ENDS Menu list-->
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't really do much when you copy it directly into a jsfiddle (a website used to 'mock up' and test your HTML, CSS and JS), and there's not much description about what you are expecting/wanting to happen, so there's going to be some guess work here...

I *think* there are 2 problems here.

**The HTML**

First, the `<li>` that has the subnavigation `<ul>` inside it has some incorrect html.
The `<a href="members.html">Members</a>` needs to be before the `<ul>`, not inside it.

So it should look like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="members.html">Members</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="board.html">Board of Directors</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="committee.html">Committee</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**The CSS**

Second, you are trying to display the subnavigation `<ul>` (by default this is display: none) when you hover on the `<a>` tag, but you need to do it when you hover the `<li>`, because it's that element that contains the subnavigation `<ul>`.

So it should look like this:

```
.nav-list li ul {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.nav-list li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Here's a fiddle with my tweaks, hopefully that'll get you back on track.

http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/ve9Ub/

Comment: You are wonderful! Thank you! thank you! Now I can see both sub-navs, but I'm trying to make the height of the sub-nav "li" shorter and I can't. I really really appreciate it!

Comment: When you say 'make it shorter' do you mean you want them to appear side by side?  If you want that, you'll have to set a width on the subnav `<ul>`